# VS Code - Syntax highlighting and IntelliSense for web components containing CSS or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, intellisense, syntax-highlighting

I have a PHP file that includes custom web components, like this:

```
<my-component>

    console.log('Hello, world!');

</my-component>
```

As you can see the component is an extension of the script tag and contains JavaScript. I have another component that contains CSS, same principle.

The issue I am having is that there seems to be no syntax highlighting or IntelliSense support for JavaScript/CSS in custom tags in VS Code, making it frustrating to work with.

I have found the [following](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-html-languageservice/blob/main/docs/customData.md) which explains (not very comprehensively) how to register custom tags, but there is no mention of associating a different language with them.

I don't want to write a full-blown extension for a feature that should be pretty straight-forward. If anyone could point me in the right direction or could explain how to get this to work it would be greatly appreciated.